# Magento 2 On checkout page, where shippingAddressFromData is fetched from database?

Tags: magento2, checkout, forms, shipping-address

On checkout page, what is the class (PHP) that provides data to "mage-cache-storage", which is a key in 'Local Storage'.
About 'Local Storage':
https://superuser.com/questions/356494/what-is-store-in-local-storage-used-for-in-chrome

I'm interested specifically by 'shippingAddressFromData' object from JSON with key 'mage-cache-storage'.

I'd like to know where is the declaration in php/xml side of Magento 2 that  links 'shippingAddressFromData' and the php code that provides the data for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the Shipping Address Data is loaded from the Checkout Config Object: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Model/DefaultConfigProvider.php#L323

The Checkout is built from a single block with a pretty complex js layout, which then loads the ui components which render the checkout. (https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml#L11)

Somehow, the ui components have to receive the session specific data and configuration. I think this happens here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/templates/onepage.phtml#L26

The method [getCheckoutConfig](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Block/Onepage.php#L91) returns a merged config from a list of [ConfigProviderInterfaces](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Model/CompositeConfigProvider.php#L31), which is implemented by the [DefaultConfigProvider](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Model/DefaultConfigProvider.php#L323)

Answer (score 2):

Object returned by method shippingAddressFromData stored in browsers LocalStorage and was saved during filling shipping address form (on key press event)